# Where would you put the code that a resque worker and a rails controller share?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a rails controller and a resque worker. Both share a couple of functions. Where should I put these functions so that I can follow the DRY principle and Rails conventions?

Comment: What are those functions responsible for doing?

Comment: These functions are creating a elaborate data structure which is made up of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this sounds like a good case for a service layer. One of my coworkers wrote up a nice summary of the concept: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/01/10/does-my-rails-app-need-a-service-layer/

> In Domain-Driven Design, Evans defines a service as an operation
> offered as an interface that stands alone in the model. In other
> words, a service is an action, not a thing. And instead of forcing the
> operation into an existing object, we should encapsulate it in a
> separate, stateless service.
>
> ...
>
> A domain service scripts a use-case
> involving multiple domain objects. Forcing this logic into a domain
> object is awkward because these use-cases often involve rules outside
> the responsibility of any single object.

Service layers are a common feature in many other web app MVC frameworks and something many Rails applications choose to use when fat models do not provide an appropriate encapsulation of responsibilities in their problem domain.

Without knowing more I'm afraid I can't offer a more specific answer. My next step would be to try to consider what this service should be named. Is it a factory that build something we have a name for? Do is fulfill a specific role we can name it after?

Comment: hah, I was putting such code to `lib/services` for ages now! Good to know that I'm not alone :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're certainly not alone. I would however add services to `app/services`. They are an essential part of your app and deserve to be organized as such, it also helps prevent `lib` from becoming a catch-all. The apps I have worked on will often have several subfolders under `app` not found in a default Rails app. Don't be afraid to add your own as needed.

Comment: Good idea, actually. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what these methods actually do, but `/lib` might be a good spot.

Comment: as answered above they do some calculations and create a elaborate data structure used by the view of a controller and in email sent by the resque worker.